# Cannot find the register link phtml file

Tags: magento2, php, theme, frontend, html

I enabled the path template suggestion and It doesn't show the path for the 'Create an account' link.
Reading the html home page source I've saw these tags:

```
<ul class="header links">
    <li class="greet welcome" data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
        <!-- ko if: customer().fullname  -->
        <span data-bind="text: new String('Benvenuto, %1!').replace('%1', customer().firstname)">
        </span>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: customer().fullname  -->
        <span data-bind="html:'Testo di benvenuto predefinito!'"></span>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </li>
<li class="authorization-link" data-label="o">
    <a href="https://mysiteurl/index.php/customer/account/login/">
        Login    </a>
</li>

<li><a href="https://mysiteurl/index.php/customer/account/create/" >Create an account</a></li></ul>
```

This is the path for the greeting block:

```
/var/www/vhosts/mysite/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml
```

For the Login block:

```
/var/www/vhosts/mysite/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/link/authorization.phtml
```

Where is the 'create an account' phtml file that contains the 'li' tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link does not come from a template file.
It is added via layout (`view/frontend/layout/default.xml` from the customer module) via these lines:

```
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\RegisterLink" name="register-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Create an Account</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
```

The link is rendered via the method `Magento\Customer\Block\Account\RegisterLink::_toHtml` which calls the parent class `_toHtml` method.  Parent class is `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link` and the method looks like this:

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    if (false != $this->getTemplate()) {
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }

    return '<li><a ' . $this->getLinkAttributes() . ' >' . $this->escapeHtml($this->getLabel()) . '</a></li>';
}
```

there is no template for the register link block so it gets rendered by this line `return '<li><a ' . $this->getLinkAttributes() . ' >' . $this->escapeHtml($this->getLabel()) . '</a></li>';`

Comment: The method _toHtml() contains a : #<li class="nav item'#, I don't think it is the right method.